Trigger child click event when parent is clicked(HTML, CSS, JS)
The problem is that i have  that have padding containing 
I want to trigger checkbox input change when  is click(  padding)
<ul>
  <li key={ index } className={ `${ styles.option } ${ handleTravelTypesStyle( index ) }` }>
    <input type="checkbox" name= "traveltype1" id="traveltype1" onChange="( event ) => handleTravelTypesInput( event.target )"/>
    <label htmlFor="traveltype1">Type1</label>
  </li>
</ul>

I hope i can fix it with a simple solution

what are the chances that the question and answer made the same mistake in markdown usage

<ul>
  <li key={ index } className={ `${ styles.option } ${ handleTravelTypesStyle( index ) }` } onclick="triggerCheckbox(event)">
    <input type="checkbox" name="traveltype1" id="traveltype1" onchange="handleTravelTypesInput(event.target)" />
    <label for="traveltype1">Type1</label>
  </li>
</ul>

JavaScript to Trigger the Checkbox Click:
You can use a JavaScript function that will be triggered when the <li> is clicked. This function will find the checkbox within the clicked <li> and manually trigger its click event.
function triggerCheckbox(event) {
  // Prevent the default label click behavior to avoid double triggering
  event.preventDefault();

  // Find the checkbox inside the clicked <li>
  const checkbox = event.currentTarget.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  // Trigger the checkbox click event
  if (checkbox) {
    checkbox.click();
  }
}

